# Why does "Riemannian Geometry cease to play the role it played before" while working with rheonomic constraints?

Tags: classical-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

I am reading *Scleronomic and rheonomic systems: The law of conservation of energy* in *The Variational Principles of Mechanics* by *Cornelius Lanczos*. This is the concerned excerpt:

> Rheonomic systems are within the scope of analytical approach, but we **lose certain consequences** which hold only for scleronomic systems. In the first place, differentiation of the equations  $$\begin{align}x_1 &= f_1(q_1,q_2,\ldots, q_n, t),\\ &....................\\ &....................\\ z_N &= f_{3N}(q_1,q_2,\ldots, q_n, t),\end{align}\tag{18.3}$$ with respect to $t$ yields:  $$\begin{align}\dot x_1 &= \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial q_1}~\mathrm d\dot q_1 + \ldots + \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial q_n}~\mathrm d\dot  q_n + \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial t} \\&..................................\\ &..................................\\  \dot z_{N} &= \frac{\partial f_{3N}}{\partial q_1}~\mathrm d\dot q_1 + \ldots + \frac{\partial f_{3N}}{\partial q_n}~\mathrm d\dot  q_n + \frac{\partial f_{3N}}{\partial t}\end{align}\,. \tag{18.4}$$ If these expressions are substituted in the definition of the kinetic energy $$T= \frac12\sum_i^n m_iv_i^2,\tag{15.8}$$ it will not come out as purely  quadratic form of the generalised velocities $\dot q_i;$ we obtain additional new terms which are linear in velocities, and others which are independent of velocities. The **Riemannian geometry ceases to play the role that it has played before.**

Here, author mentions explicitly two times in the form of bold sentences above that the Riemannian geometry loses *certain consequences* while working with rheonomic constraints.

I could not comprehend which  "*certain consequences*" he is talking about.

I know rheonomic constraints cannot have the conservation law of energy; but does it drastically affect the analytical approach? this is the thing I'm not getting.

What did he mean by "*Riemannian Geometry ceases to play the role it has played before*"?

Is it about the conservation Law?

Could anyone explain me what he tried to mean?

Comment: I think the author is merely referring to the fact that no definition of configuration space in terms of a Riemannian manifold is possible now, where geodesics are solution of E.L. equations (in case of absence of active forces).